# How to properly store and manipulate(show/edit) dates on international website

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm working on a project using PHP (codeigniter) and mysql as DBMS.
This project will face situations like this:

User_A located in France creates an event. (His PC shows him that it is 18PM)
User_B located in Russia creates a second event at the same time than User_A.

When User_C from USA comes to the plataform to list all the events across the globe he finds only 2 events where both of them are starting at the same time. Of course, in his (USA) Timezone.

Here are my questions:

1. What's the best way to get the User_X timezone?

   1.a) Make a POST request to the server on login and store the Timezone into a session variable?
      1.b) While registering the account, ask the user for his timezone. 
      1.c) Something else?
2. I'm not being able to convert a particular Timespan into different human readable datetimes according to different timezones. I was trying this with codeigniter:

using the date helper from [here](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/helpers/date_helper.html)

```
$gmt  = local_to_gmt( now() , 'UTC', true );
$gmt1 = local_to_gmt( now() , 'UM2', true );
$gmt2 = local_to_gmt( now() , 'UP25', true);

echo "<b>UTC</b><br/>";
echo unix_to_human($gmt, TRUE, 'EU')  ;echo "<br/>";
echo mdate($datestring, $time);

echo "<b>(UTC - 2:00) Mid-Atlantic, Ascention Is., St Helena</b><br/>";
echo unix_to_human($gmt1, TRUE, 'EU')  ;echo "<br/>";
echo mdate($datestring, $gmt1);

echo "<b>(UTC + 3:30) Tehran</b>";  echo "<br/>";
echo unix_to_human($gmt2, TRUE, 'EU')  ;echo "<br/>";
echo mdate($datestring, $gmt2);
```

The problem is that this is outputing the same our for all of those formated datetimes.

```
UTC
2014-01-17 18:15:29
2014-01-17 06:15:pm
(UTC - 2:00) Mid-Atlantic, Ascention Is., St Helena
2014-01-17 18:15:29
2014-01-17 06:15:pm
(UTC + 3:30) Tehran
2014-01-17 18:15:29
2014-01-17 06:15:pm
```

_3. Last question: How should timespans be stored into the database? 
   Do i just need a Timespan data type column and when retriving the data transform it into a datatime formated to the user's timezone?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, I would recommend that you store all dates in the DB based on UTC as a datetime type.  You can leave timezone conversion up to the application layer.

Second, I would recommend you become familiar with PHP DateTime, DateTimeZone, DateInterval, etc. classes.  They will make your life much easier when dealing with timezone conversions, datetime math, etc.

So, say you have read a date from MySQL datetime field, you could do time zone conversion like this:

```
$db_datetime = ...; // your datetime from DB now stored as string
$utc_timezone = new DateTimeZone('UTC');
$utc_datetime = new DateTime($db_datetime, $utc_timezone);

$timezone = ...; // user-defined timezone that you get from somewhere (user input, user settign in DB, etc.) probably best stored in format equal to timzone identifiers available via calling DateTimeZone::listIdentifiers(DateTimeZone::ALL)
$user_datetimezone = new DateTimeZone($timezone);
$user_datetime = clone $utc_datetime;
$user_datetime->setTimezone($user_datetimezone);
```

As to your question on how to best set the user's timezone.  This is really up to you as far as what works best in your application. Do you have logged in users and store user settings?  If so maybe this is a setting stored in DB.  Do you have anonymous users?  If so, maybe you store timezone in session.  Either way at some point you would need to build a mechanism to input the timezone (perhaps you can even make best guess at timezone based on user IP geolocation).